# breadcrumbs are not showing in magento cms pages

Tags: magento, magento-1.5, breadcrumbs

Breadcrumbs are not displaying in any cms page. What may be the problem?

I checked the

> admin -> system ->config-> web -> default pages -> Show Breadcrumbs for CMS Pages

option yes.

`$crumbs` variable is coming as null in page/html/breadcrumbs.phtml.

Please advise me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply i add below code in template file like 1-column.phtml that works me !

```
echo $this->getLayout()->getBlock('breadcrumbs')->toHtml();
```

magneto version 1.5.1.0

Comment: In my case, [ echo $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs') ] was missing in [ template/page/3columns.phtml ].

Comment: @chapagain: I have red your blog, thats great i inspired of blog.. i ll start blog ASAP. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Normally Magento will not display breadcrump on CMS pages, you need to customized the breadcrump code to display it on cms pages. I think the following link might help you.

http://www.gowrisankar.com/adding-breadcrump-to-cms-pages-in-magento#.Us8LldJdUfQ